# MySQL - Find a value of a string

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables. I want to match the first table with the second one. The problem is, the tables that are given to me is just not designed the way it's supposed to be designed like for instance at least have a primary key or a good table structure. Here are the tables:

Table A:

```
| receipt            |
| ------------------ |
| 2021/IV/21/Eddy//  |
| 2021-04-21/ Mat    |
```

Table B:

```
| Name     |
| -------- |
| Eddie    |
| Mat      |
| Eddy     |
| Alexa    |
```

Another problem is that Table A was manually input so there's not consistency on the data.

How can I extract the individual's name on Table A then match it with table B?

Thank you.

Comment: This will find all the records from TableA with a matching name in TableB: `SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB on TableA.receipt LIKE CONCAT('%',TableB.Name,'%')`.

Comment: you can do a %like% match but with such a flimsy data model you are likely to run into  complications, eg *Alex* is like *Alex* and *Alexa*

Comment: And no-one can help you when someone typed `Eddie` and did mean `Eddy` ( or `Alex` vs. `Alexa` ), or any other, typo's.  (Yes I know that `Eddy`,`Eddie`,`Alex`  and `Alexa` can all valid names, and need not be typo's)

Answer (score 1):

you could create a function, in order to find the name from TableA:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `find_Name`(receipt VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET utf8mb4
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE posLastSpace INT;    

   SELECT LOCATE(' ',trim(reverse(replace(receipt,'/',' ')))) into posLastSpace;
   
RETURN TRIM(SUBSTRING(trim(replace(receipt,'/',' ')),-posLastSpace));
END
```

After this the result from `SELECT receipt, find_Name(receipt) FROM TableA` would be:

| receipt | find_Name(receipt) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/IV/21/Eddy// | Eddy |
| 2021-04-21/ Mat | Mat |

A match with TableB can then be done using:

```
SELECT
   TableA.receipt,
   find_Name(TableA.receipt),
   TableB.Name
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.Name = find_Name(TableA.receipt);
```

The results for the third column (`TableB.Name`) will be NULL when there is no matching record found.